# Vorzeitigkeit im Konjunktiv Futur

Tags: tense, future

Ich möchte ausdrücken, dass wenn (Konjunktiv) in der Zukunft (Futur) etwas unwahrscheinliches (Irrealis) geschehen sein wird (Vorzeitigkeit), danach (Nachzeitigkeit) etwas anderes geschehen würde (Konjunktiv), hab aber absolut keine Ahnung, wie ich diese Zeiten korrekt bilde.

Beispiel:

> Ich sitze jetzt [im Präsens] hier und stelle mir vor: Nachdem ich den Mann gerettet habe / gerettet hätte / gerettet haben würde, wäre er mir dankbar / würde er mir dankbar sein / sei er mir dankbar.

Was ist (grammatisch) richtig? Und was ist (im alltägliche Sprachgebrauch) Usus?

Comment: Im alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch bildet man solche Sätze nicht. Futur II Konjunktiv würde von jedem gemieden werden ;) wie die Pest, und wahrscheinlich würde man den Sachverhalt auseinandernehmen in sowas wie "Ich würde ihn retten und danach würde er mir dankbar sein müssen" (also ins Präsens verschieben und die Nachzeitigkeit mit einem Adverb ausdrücken - Das drückt - zugegebenermaßen falsch - genau aus, was du meinst)

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt tatsächlich einen Konjunktiv II für Futur II. Vollständige Flexionstabellen sind auf Wiktionary einzusehen. Für *[retten](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:retten)* in der ersten Person Singular, Aktiv:

> ich würde gerettet haben

Daraus folgt:

> Ich sitze jetzt [im Präsens] hier und stelle mir vor: Nachdem ich den Mann <s>gerettet habe</s> / <s>gerettet hätte</s> / **gerettet haben würde**...

Der zweite Teil des Satzes müsste, wenn ich mich jetzt nicht schwer vertue, dann Futur I, Zustandspassiv, Konjunktiv II sein — und in der dritten Person natürlich:

> er würde dankbar sein

Folglich:

> ...<s>wäre er mir dankbar</s> / würde er mir dankbar sein / <s>sei er mir dankbar</s>.

Und als ganzes:

> Ich sitze jetzt hier und stelle mir vor: Nachdem ich den Mann gerettet haben würde, würde er mir dankbar sein.

Comment: Die Tabellen in Wiktionary sind etwas irreführend, denn der  Konjunktiv II im Futur I oder Futur II ist identisch mit der würde-Ersatzform für den Konjunktiv. "... gerettet hätte, wäre er mir dankbar" ist also auch richtig, und formal nicht von der würde-Variante zu unterscheiden, zumal auch im Indikativ das Futur gerne durch das Präsens ersetzt wird ("Morgen gehe ich ins Kino"). "Habe" und "sei" sind natürlich Konjunktiv I.

Comment: @dirkt Ersatzformen werden in der Tabelle gar nicht gelistet. Die von dir genannten Formen sind Präteritum bzw. Plusquamperfekt und für Futur I und Futur II inkorrekt.

Comment: Natürlich werden sie nicht gelistet, und es sind auch nicht die Ersatzformen für Futur I oder II. Wenn es unklar ist: "Wenn ich rettete" und "wenn ich retten würde" sind bedeutungsgleich, und beidesmal Konjunktiv II Gegenwart. Die zweite Form ist *nicht* Konjunktiv I Futur, auch wenn sie *formal* aus Umlautung des Futur Indikativ gebildet wird (genauso, wie Konjunktiv II Gegenwart aus Umlautung des Indikativ Imperfekt gebildet wird). Die Konjunktivformen sind defekt, es gibt nur Gegenwart und Vergangenheit je für I und II. Wiktionary macht da einfach Unsinn.

Comment: Hä? Die Formen werden aus Gegenwart und Vergangenheit hergeleitet, aber deswegen sind sie nicht auf diese Zeitformen beschränkt. In der Praxis ist es hingegen der sinnvollste Einsatz. Futur II im Konjunktiv II ist nun wirklich kein Alltagsfall und deswegen auch ungewohnt, aber trotz alledem kann man diese Zeitformen bilden. Das Beispiel von OP verdeutlicht dies sehr gut. Es ist ungewöhnlich so was zu sagen, aber möglich.

Comment: Nochmal: Es gibt keinen Unterschied zwischen "wenn ich rettete" und "wenn ich retten würde". Wäre die zweite Form "Konjunktiv II Futur", und die erste Form "Konjunktiv II Präsens", müsste die erste auf die Gegenwart beschränkt sein, und die zweite auf die Zukunft. So ist es aber nicht, beide sind austauschbar. Es gibt also keine eigenständige Form "Konjunktiv II Futur": Das ist die würde-Ersatzform für den Konjunktiv II Gegenwart, und man kann beide für Gegenwart, Zukunft oder den Allgemeinfall benutzen.

Comment: Nur weil zufälligerweise die würde-Ersatzform aus dem Indikativ Futur hergeleitet wird, ist es kein Futur. Für welche Zeiten die Konjunktivformen benutzt werden, hat nichts mit der Zeitform des Indikativ zu tun, aus dem sie abgeleitet werden (von Vorzeitigkeit und Nicht-Vorzeitigkeit abgesehen).

Comment: Okay, du hast recht und ich meine Ruhe.

Answer (score 0):

Für alle praktischen Belange (nicht zum Durchexerzieren theoretisch möglicher Formen des Konjunktivs):

Es ist ein Unterschied, ob du von einer Rettung sprichst, die - wenn auch nur in deiner Vorstellung - real ist:

> Ich sitze hier und stelle mir vor, der Mann wäre mir, nachdem ich ihn gerettet habe, dankbar.

Oder von einer Rettung, die auch in deiner Vorstellung unrealisiert bleibt:

> Ich sitze hier und stelle mir vor, der Mann wäre mir, wenn ich ihn gerettet hätte, dankbar. [1]

Aus diesem Satz wird klar, dass die Rettung nicht stattfand.

Möglich wäre auch folgende Formulierung:

> Ich sitze hier und stelle mir vor, der Mann würde mir wohl dankbar sein, wenn ich ihn gerettet hätte.

Auch dies geht davon aus, dass die Rettung nicht stattfand (*hätte*). Allerdings ist sie weniger elegant und fürs Schriftliche nicht gut geeignet. In mündlicher Sprache verwenden aber viele Leute solche Formulierungen mit *würde*.

Um das  Bild noch etwas zu verwirren: Im zweiten Beispiel habe ich bewusst *wenn* statt *nachdem* gesetzt, um die Irrealität zu unterstreichen. Der Satz funktioniert aber auch mit *nachdem*:

> Ich sitze hier und stelle mir vor, der Mann wäre mir, nachdem ich ihn gerettet hätte, dankbar.

Allerdings muss man dann schon sehr genau hinhören (oder hinlesen), um die Nuancen zu verstehen. Hier legt der Sprecher offensichtlich Wert darauf, zu unterstreichen, dass er das Dankbarsein des Mannes für einen Zeitpunkt nach dessen Gerettetwerden erwartet hätte. Das ist aber eigentlich eine überflüssige Unterstreichung, denn wann sonst sollte der Mann dankbar sein (wenn überhaupt)?

---

[1] Nota bene, aus Anlass der Diskussion, die sich hierzu hernach in den Kommentaren entspann: Diese Sätze sind gleichermaßen präsentisch wie futurisch lesbar. Deutlich machen kann man das, indem man die zeitlichen Bezüge verbalisiert:

Zukünftige imaginierte Handlung:

> Ich sitze hier und stelle mir vor, der Mann wäre mir **morgen**, nachdem ich ihn **morgen** zuvor gerettet hätte, dankbar.

Gegenwärtige imaginierte Handlung:

> Ich sitze hier und stelle mir vor, der Mann wäre mir **jetzt**, nachdem ich ihn zuvor gerettet hätte, dankbar.

(Formulierungen mit *haben würde* sind auch möglich; sie unterscheiden sich aber in der Bedeutung nicht von denen mit *hätte*.)

Comment: Satz 2 und 3 suggeriert aber Vergangenheit. Gestern ist er verunglückt. Ich habe ihn nicht gerettet. Jetzt sitze ich hier und stelle mir vor, wenn ich ihn (gestern) gerettet hätte, wäre der Mann mir dankbar (bzw. würde er ... sein).

Comment: Nun gut: *Ich sitze hier und denke mir, der Mann wäre mir, hätte ich ihn gestern gerettet, heute dankbar.*

Comment: Keiner deiner Beispielsätze gibt leider die Intention der Frage richtig wieder, dass das irreale Geschehnis in der Zukunft liegt. Daher hast du zwar viel Schönes (und auch Richtiges) über den Konjunktiv geschrieben, aber leider die Frage nicht beantwortet.

Comment: Ich meine, meine Sätze sind auch für den an die Zukunft Denkenden gut: *Ich sitze hier und denke mir, den morgigen Tag planend, der Mann wäre mir morgen wohl dankbar, hätte ich ihn denn dann (am morgigen Tage, doch noch vor dem hier bedachten Moment) gerettet; doch ist mir das Retten prinzipiell viel zu mühsam, und das wäre es auch morgen, also nehme ich Abstand von der Idee, ihn morgen zu retten.* - Will sagen: Es gibt einfach keine eigene Form für Konjunktiv II Futur. Wir haben die Präsensform, und diese ist sowohl für präsentische wie futurische Situationen verwendbar. Liege ich da falsch?